# Git: ignoring .htaccess… just not always

Tags: git, .htaccess, gitignore

Here's the scenario:

1. I want to track .htaccess in my repo, since it contains essential configuration.
2. I want to keep prying eyes away from my dev site, so I add HTTP auth directives to .htaccess in dev.
3. During development, I don't want Git to constantly tell me that .htaccess is modified, nor do I want .htaccess to be included in any `git add -A` command.
4. I do, however, want the option to add and commit .htaccess. (If I make changes that should propagate to production.)

What's the best way to do this? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ignore changes in a file, use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged .htaccess
```

This command sets a flag on the file such that Git treats it as if there are no uncommitted changes to the file, regardless of the contents of file your working copy.

You need to undo the previous before you can stage and commit new changes.

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged .htaccess
git commit .htaccess
```